# Is there any way to load redirected page in div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some links (like first link in below) and want to get links that is redirected to (like second one)

For example:

I have link below:

> http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/146.1435-5655

And need to get this link:

> http://link.springer.com/journal/146

that redirect (or converted) from first one.

When I use `.load()` function in jQuery it return some javascript codes that I think it get second link from `dx.doi.org` server.

How can I get second link? (`http://link.springer.com/journal/146`)

In other word, I have `http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/146.1435-5655` and need only `http://link.springer.com/journal/146` in string (not content of `http://link.springer.com/journal/146`)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="swPicForm">TODO write content</div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#swPicForm").load("http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/146.1435-5655", null, function() {
         alert($("#swPicForm").html());
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is:

```
function (e){return v.access(this,function(e){var n=this[0]||{},r=0,i=this.length;if(e===t)return n.nodeType===1?n.innerHTML.replace(ht,""):t;if(typeof e=="string"&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){e=e.replace(dt,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;r<i;r++)n=this[r]||{},n.nodeType===1&&(v.cleanData(n.getElementsByTagName("*")),n.innerHTML=e);n=0}catch(s){}}n&&this.empty().append(e)},null,e,arguments.length)}
```

thanks all

Comment: You can't do this with ajax. If request does redirect you have no control over it